# Inputting input in a command?

Tags: command-line, openvpn

I'm running a command through a program that needs to create an OpenVPN account. After putting in this line to start making the account:

```
cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa; . ./vars; ./build-key username
```

I need to have it put in no input 10 times [like pressing enter,] and then press y twice. It needs to all be in this one line. Is this possible? Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
root@suffice-vpn:~# cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa; . ./vars; <<<$'\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nyy' ./build-key username
NOTE: If you run ./clean-all, I will be doing a rm -rf on /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys
Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
..............+++
.....................+++
writing new private key to 'username.key'
-----
You are about to be asked to enter information that will be incorporated
into your certificate request.
What you are about to enter is what is called a Distinguished Name or a DN.
There are quite a few fields but you can leave some blank
For some fields there will be a default value,
If you enter '.', the field will be left blank.
-----
Country Name (2 letter code) [US]:State or Province Name (full name) [NY]:Locality Name (eg, city) [Merrick]:Organization Name (eg, company) [IceWare]:Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) [IceWare]:Common Name (eg, your name or your server's hostname) [username]:Name [server]:Email Address [iceware@programmer.net]:
Please enter the following 'extra' attributes
to be sent with your certificate request
A challenge password []:An optional company name []:Using configuration from /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/openssl-1.0.0.cnf
Check that the request matches the signature
Signature ok
The Subject's Distinguished Name is as follows
countryName           :PRINTABLE:'US'
stateOrProvinceName   :PRINTABLE:'NY'
localityName          :PRINTABLE:'Merrick'
organizationName      :PRINTABLE:'IceWare'
organizationalUnitName:PRINTABLE:'IceWare'
commonName            :PRINTABLE:'username'
name                  :PRINTABLE:'server'
emailAddress          :IA5STRING:'iceware@programmer.net'
Certificate is to be certified until Jan 14 16:59:03 2026 GMT (3650 days)
Sign the certificate? [y/n]:CERTIFICATE WILL NOT BE CERTIFIED: I/O error
root@suffice-vpn:/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa#
```

As you can see, it goes through the process filling in the blanks [keeping all that information that I want to remain the same] but then I get this I/O error.

Comment: Not too elegant, but in many cases this works: `cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa; . ./vars; <<<$'\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nyy' ./build-key username`. The problem is this enters an additional newline after the last `y`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the pretty quick reply. I tried that, but it doesnt seem to work. I will add the output to the main thread.

Comment: Maybe you need another ENTER keystroke after the first `y`? `cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa; . ./vars; <<<$'\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\ny\ny' ./build-key username`

Comment: Got the same error message. I looked into it and found out that its something related to not pressing "y" on one of the 2 prompts.

Comment: Weird. Try [`expect`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) (I'm linking the Wikipedia page because I can't find a Q/A about it and Wikipedia has some examples, but look also at the `man` page). Can't give more guidance though, I've never used it.

Comment: Maybe you need to add a `\n` after the last `y`: `$'\n....y\ny\n'`

Comment: Didn't work. I used this, at first: cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa; . ./vars; <<<$'n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n' ./build-key username That command successfully skipped all the input lines, but even after adding yy I still got the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it by using this command:

```
cd /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa; . ./vars; ./build-key --batch username
```